# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 3000;

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I have a `.env` file in my root directory with `PORT = 3000;` inside

In my `app.js`, I am using the .env file to listen to port 3000

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!!!');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

After trying to run the file, I get the following error

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 3000;

I'm on a Mac, so I tried using `sudo lsof -i :3000` in the terminal and am asked for my password.

I type in my password and hit Enter but nothing happens.

How can I remove the error? I believe my password is correct. I did get a huge Mac OS update today--could that cause some password related issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `app.js` file to

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require('dotenv').config();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!!!');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

resolves the issue, but `PORT` in `.env` is not being read...

Comment: You need to `require` dotenv at the top of the file

Comment: Doing that gives me Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Comment: That wouldn't fix your error but it's necessary for using `process.env.PORT`. I think what you need is `lsof -i:3000` **without** the space

Comment: Then, grab the pid and run `kill -9 {pid}`, replacing `{pid}` with the returned pid

Comment: Actually, the space doesn't seem to make a difference, if a pid is returned from @bilash answer, kill that instead

Comment: Tried without the space, and terminal just gives me back my current directory : /

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this *error* using this command on *Windows* :

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3000.
```

After entering this command above, you will be given this TCP address:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12356
  TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       12356
```

And then run:

```
taskkill /PID 12356 /F
```

eg:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\nodejs>netstat -ano | findstr :3000

  TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       12356
  TCP    [::]:3000              [::]:0                 LISTENING       12356

C:\Users\Desktop\nodejs>taskkill /PID 12356 /F

SUCCESS: The process with PID 12356 has been terminated.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Try this command:

```
sudo ps -ef | grep 3000
```

Comment: I receive 501 20005 19406   0  9:22PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep 4000 what should I do from here?

Comment: You need to run ps -ef, then look for the process which you ran before under the CMD column.
My guess it would be node ./app.js. After you located that, you need to get the PID of that process, and then run kill {PID}
This worked for me.
or sudo kill -9 {PID} // to force kill with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

you should delete semicolon behind port number

for example PORT=3000

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to terminate your port which is running now.

Use the following -

1. `netstat -ano | findstr :3000`
2. `taskkill /PID 12356 /F`

`3000` & `12356` will change as per need.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply change port number

from 3000
to 3010 or what

Just stay away form already used port